# jquery load specific content from a file

Tags: jquery, load, getjson

i'm trying to get specific text from a plain-text organized by tags or whatever; and then load on a existing div or create on the fly a div to load on it.

dont know if with json it could be ok

i've tried creating a .json file data_prod.js like this:

```
{"articles":
        [
            {
                "title1":"bla bla bla"
            },
            {
                "title2":"bla bla bla"
            },
            ...
        ]
}
```

in my html code i've written that function :

```
    $.getJSON("data_prod.js",function(data)
        {
            var div_data = data.title1;
            $(div_data).appendTo("#tt_mn");
        });
```

the content i'd like to load in these case is only title1 in a div existing called #tt_mn

there's something wrong

now i've modified.

```
data.json

{
   "articles": [{ "title": "fresa" }, { "title": "limon" }, { "title": "naranja" } ]
}
```

test_json.html

```
<div id="op">push me</div>  
<div id="tt_mn" data-articleidx="1"></div>
<script>
$('#op').live("click", function() {
    // get the index of the article for which the title should be obtained
    var idx = $(this).data('articleidx');
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
        // be safe and the data parameter conformity prior to extracting the title
        if (data && data.articles && idx < data.articles.length) {
            $("<div>" + data.articles[idx].title + "</div>").appendTo("#tt_mn");
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rapaheldg/c9A8Z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first change a bit your json so you have the same "title" property for all items:

```
{
   "articles": [{ "title": "title 1" }, { "title": "title 2" }, ... ]
}
```

Then, in the callback of the .getJSON() function, go through all your items and generate html markup with the title values.

I think the most efficient way of applying markup is build an array of strings representing the desired markup and append it all at once. A `for` loop will also be more efficient over the jquery .each() or .map().

```
$.getJSON("data_prod.js", function(data) {
    var titles = [];
    for (var i=0; i<data.articles.length;i++) {
        titles.push("<div>" + data.articles[i].title + "</div>");
    }
    $(titles.join('')).appendTo("#tt_mn");
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/7xjku/)**

---

**Edit:**

So if you like to display one specific title from a button click, you could add a "data-" attribute specifying which article you'd like to get the title:

```
<button data-articleidx="1">Get title</button>
```

And then:

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    // get the index of the article for which the title should be obtained
    var idx = $(this).data('articleidx');
    $.getJSON("data_prod.js", function(data) {
        // be safe and the data parameter conformity prior to extracting the title
        if (data && data.articles && idx < data.articles.length) {
            $("<div>" + data.articles[idx].title + "</div>").appendTo("#tt_mn");
        }
    });
});
```

I still suggest you change the json to have the same property name for titles. I can't think of a reason why they are actually "title1", "title2"...

Comment: its ok but i only want to display one title depending of which button it'd would have clicked. not all the tittles

Comment: in my case i click in a div to load specific title, would it be the same data-articleidx="1" for my div???

Comment: Yes, whatever the element, I've used a button just for the sake of the example.

Comment: On which line ? I cannot answer you without seeing your implementation.

Comment: i dont want to be bored but i've been since 2 two days to get out this neverending point for finishing that webpage. and i'm in trouble with this. url: http://www.dielecsur.com/p7 - spanish section->productos->industrial->protecciones . please dont banner me

Comment: var  idx = $(this).data('articleidx');

Comment: You are doing `alert(articleidx, "alert window");` but `articleidx` variable does not exist. You should do `alert(idx, "alert window");`

Comment: You also forgot to surround the code I wrote in a click handler on a div. It's difficult to help because of the way all the pages are loaded. Also I don't know what is "ind_prot.tcl".

Comment: not exactly, i've updated my function deleting alert line. but it doesn't show anything in the div :s

Comment: Check my previous comment about the click handler. Also try to think of the workflow: 1. load content (with the data- attribute), 2. attach a click event to the loaded elements in which I extract the data- attribute. 3. get the json and extract the title for the specified index.

Comment: Then remove the code from "prod_industria.html". But there is obviously a problem with the .tcl file because it shows "este es el contenido de ind_prot.tcl" instead of the "test_json.html" page

Comment: it's works if i load content from var data = { "articles": [ ... ] }, but if i load from external file it doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot really help you with your full implementation (and this is not really the goal), I can only provide advices and help you resolve specific bugs, which I think I pretty much did a lot. Debug your code line by line and see what happens.

Comment: that all works. my problem was that i used jquery 1.4.2 instead 1.4.4 or newest. THANK YOU !!

Comment: You're welcome ;-) You should definetely update to the latest version, it's way more optimized.

Answer (score 1):

First fix your JSON by using the same `title` property for all articles instead of having a different property name (title1, title2, ...):

```
{ 
    "articles": 
    [
        {
            "title":"bla bla bla"
        },
        {
            "title":"bla bla bla"
        },
        ...
    ] 
}
```

and then you could loop through those articles and use the `title` property:

```
$.getJSON("data_prod.js",function(data) {
    $.each(data.articles, function(index, article) {
        $('<div/>', {
            text: article.title
        }).appendTo("#tt_mn");
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE:

If you want to keep the original structure of your JSON and load only `title1` you could do the following:

```
$.getJSON("data_prod.js", function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.articles.length; i++) {
        var article = data.articles[i];
        for (var prop in article) {
            if (article.hasOwnProperty('title1')) {
                var title = article.title1;
                $('<div/>', {
                    text: title
                }).appendTo("#tt_mn");
                break;
           }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `div` which you are creating is already a jQuery object why are you wrapping it again inside `$()`. You can directly use appendTo on inner jQuery object.

Comment: i'd like to have whole text content in one large file as db file and load specific text depending of what div i would clicked

Comment: @ShankarSangoli, good point, it was a bad copy paste. It's fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: but how can i load only title1 text from a json in a div??

Comment: @RaphaelD.G, you could use the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method while looping through the article. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion :

1) create the container(s) :

loading content (text / image)

2) add a very specific attribute for our script :

<div data-url="mycontect.txt">loading content (text / image)>

3) add the script to load the dynamic content :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function()){
     $('[data-url]').each(function(){

         // just making sure we have the correct instance.
         var $elem = $(this);
         // Get the url
         var url = $(this).attrr('data-url');


         $.get(url, function(html) {
             /// adding the content to the container.
             $elem.html(html); 
         });
     });

};
```

`